# Let $ \ M=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | f(x)=0 \} \ $ be a level a level surface of a differentiable function $

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $ \ M=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | f(x)=0 \} \ $ be a level a level surface of a differentiable function $ \ f  \ \ in \ \  \mathbb{R}^n \ $.

Let $ \ x_0 \in M \ $ such that $ \ || x_0|| \geq || x|| \ $ , $ \ \forall \ x \in M \ $,

then **show that** 
$ \ \large x_0=c \nabla f(x_0) \ $ ,  for  some $ \ c \in R \ $ .

**Answer:**

Since $ \ x_0 \in M , \ we \ \ must \ \ have \ \ f(x_0)=0 \\ So, \ \ \nabla f(x_0)=0 \ $

But $ x_0 \ $ may not be  $ zero $.

So how can $ x_0 \ $ can be maximum ?

**Help me.**

Comment: Correct your title. Also, $f(x) = 0$ does not imply $f'(x) = 0$.

Comment: This is certainly false unless some definition comes to the rescure. What is a level surface of a differentiable function?

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to Langrange-Multipliers. Consider 
$$
h(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 
$$
subject to 
$$
f(x)=0
$$
Then, if $x_0$ is a maximizer there holds for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\lambda \nabla f(x_0)=\nabla h(x_0)=2  x_0 
$$
Assuming $\lambda \neq 0$ (why ?), you can divide by $\lambda$ and you are done. Note that I left out some details here as this is just a short sketch.